# How to get the element of a jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I've got some autocomplete:

```
            $(".some_class").autocomplete({
                source: function(request,response){
                    //get input values and store into myArray
                    var element= $(this); //not working
```

`.some_class` is connected to input fields, which is what I actually want to have. I thought $(this) would return the the input field. Instead I'm getting this:

`Object { element={...}, options={...}, menu={...}, mehr...}`

How can I access the element? When I used it like that before, I had no problems accessing the element.

EDIT:

Actually I want the value of the name-attribute of the input-field. Do you have an Idea how to manage that?

Comment: Could you just write <code>var element=$(this).element;</code>?

Comment: $(this) is the jquery wrapper object.  You can use array indexers to access the DOM object.  Try `$(this)[0]`.  However, you may have a different problem depending on what the value of `this` is in your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
var element = this.element;
```

`element` is already a jQuery object.

Here is the demo I used for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/y7vT4/

Comment: That's it. But I never needed the element part yet when I wanted to access the element. Why do I need it here?

Comment: It's just the way the `source` method was built. I don't think they thought the element should be `this` in this case. In a method like `change`, `this` is the element.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source - It seems the "options" from the api get the "options" as `this` and "events" get the element as `this`. I'm sure they have good reasons for it haha.

Comment: The reason is simple: The data object has several useful values, other than the element, like "isMultiLine", "term", "option", etc...